# Microsoft Internet Explorer run rights - pipe problem

Tags: internet-explorer, pipe, named-pipes

i have some problems with pipe connecting from my microsoft explorer lsp layer to my server, form all other browsers its no problem, only in microsoft explorer. CreateFile allways finishes with error 5 - access denied.

So are there any special privilegues for IE? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably part of their [protected mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx).